# Timestamp to_char subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query but I need a particular format (HH24,MI,SS) for the results that I get in column "elapsed". Can I do that with a subquery?

```
SELECT
  trunc(dstamp) "DATE",
  to_char(dstamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') "Time"
, user_id
, dstamp - lag(dstamp) OVER (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY dstamp
    ) AS elapsed
, COUNT(CODE) "Lines_Picked"
, ROUND(sum(update_qty / cast(substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
    , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)) as integer))) "CASES_PICKED"
FROM v_inventory_transaction
WHERE client_id = 'USKIDS2CA'
    AND code = 'Pick'
    AND list_id IS NOT NULL
    AND STATION_ID LIKE 'R%'
    AND reference_id NOT LIKE '%-FK%'
    AND trunc(dstamp) = to_date('03/23/2022','mm/dd/yyyy') 
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    dstamp
    , cast(substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) + 1
         , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)) as integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "timestamp" from the title? Which datatype is it? `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

If it is `TIMESTAMP`, `extract` helps a lot:

```
SQL> with temp (user_id, dstamp) as
  2    (select 1, to_timestamp('27.03.2022 08:08', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  3     select 1, to_timestamp('27.03.2022 05:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select 1, to_timestamp('27.03.2022 02:28', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  5    )
  6  select user_id,
  7         dstamp,
  8         --
  9         to_char(extract (hour   from dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp)), 'FM00') ||':'||
 10         to_char(extract (minute from dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp)), 'FM00') ||':'||
 11         to_char(extract (second from dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp)), 'FM00') result
 12  from temp
 13  order by user_id, dstamp;

   USER_ID DSTAMP                              RESULT
---------- ----------------------------------- -----------
         1 27-MAR-22 02.28.00.000000000 AM     ::
         1 27-MAR-22 05.30.00.000000000 AM     03:02:00
         1 27-MAR-22 08.08.00.000000000 AM     02:38:00

SQL>
```

---

If it is `DATE`, then `ELAPSED` currently represents number of days between `dstamp` and its previous row's value per `user_id`. As it seems that that number is always less than 1 day (as you want result in `hh24:mi:ss` format), a simple option is to apply combination of

```
to_char(to_date(elapsed, 'sssss'), 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

and get the result. Step-by-step (so that you'd see which result you get for each step):

```
SQL> with temp (user_id, dstamp) as
  2    (select 1, to_date('27.03.2022 08:08', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  3     select 1, to_date('27.03.2022 05:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select 1, to_date('27.03.2022 02:28', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  5    )
  6  select user_id,
  7         dstamp,
  8         --
  9         dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp) as elapsed_days,
 10         --
 11         round((dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id order by dstamp)) *
 12         24 * 60 * 60) elapsed_seconds,
 13         --
 14         to_char(to_date(round((dstamp - lag(dstamp) over (partition by user_id
 15                                                           order by dstamp)) *
 16                               24 * 60 * 60), 'sssss'),
 17                'hh24:mi:ss') result
 18  from temp
 19  order by user_id, dstamp;

   USER_ID DSTAMP              ELAPSED_DAYS ELAPSED_SECONDS RESULT
---------- ------------------- ------------ --------------- --------
         1 27.03.2022 02:28:00
         1 27.03.2022 05:30:00   .126388889           10920 03:02:00
         1 27.03.2022 08:08:00   .109722222            9480 02:38:00

SQL>
```

However, if `elapsed` can be larger than 1 day so that it exceeds number of seconds in a day (that's 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400), that won't work so you'll have to actually *calculate* the result. However, query then becomes really ugly so you'd rather use another CTE (or a subquery) to first extract `elapsed` and work with it, instead of using `dstamp - lag(...)` all the time.

Therefore, I *hope* it is the `timestamp` after all.